# How to Bind an event in jquery, without Function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to find the way of binding event to an element.
Can we bind a JQuery without mentioning function?

[Here is my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uhxpmexe/3/)

I need to make Loan binding enable on click so that it can calls same radio button.

It's getting unbind successfully but could not be rebind to call the same click method in which it is defined.

My code :

```
$('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
  var radioButId = $(this).attr('id');
  var value = $(this).val();
    alert(value + " is clicked");

    if(value === "home")
    {
        alert("Enable Loan Link")
        $( "#ba").bind( "click" );
    }
    if(value === "dog")
    {
        alert("Disable Loan Link");
        $( "#ba").unbind( "click" );
    }   
});
```

Could someone please help.

Comment: See this: https://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: There's a reason why you can't post a JSFiddle link without code in your question: Please add the relevant / minimalistic code in your question itself! Outside links can be useful, but they may break after some time, and then your question will be useless for any future readers. Make sure to add all the necessary info in your question itself.

Comment: Please put code in your question. We should not have to go to another site to look for it. Questions should standalone, and use demos as backup. If you want help, you need to help us help you

Comment: I keep wondering why on Earth you absolutely want to write javascript without using functions. It's like "I want to drive a car, but I don't want to use the steering wheel".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*A possible way*

**Fiddle** : https://jsfiddle.net/uhxpmexe/7/

**JS** :

```
function fHardCodedFunction(){
alert("bindee");
}

function myfunction () {
  var radioButId = $(this).attr('id');
  var value = $(this).val();
    alert(value + " is clicked");
    $( "#ba").unbind( "click" );
    if(value === "home")
    {
        alert("Enable Loan Link")
        $( "#ba").on( "click", myfunction );
    }
    if(value === "dog")
    {
        alert("Disable Loan Link");
    }  
} 

$('input[type="radio"]').click(myfunction);
```

Comment: Is myfunction required? Can't we do without it as asked in question title?

Comment: @fatherazrael Yes, it is required in this way. Otherwhise how will it know what to do when rebinding the event?

Comment: @Yenne Info
Thanks. I implemented this in my solution

Answer (score 1):

You can simply enable and disable "Loan" with the `disabled` attribute.

I have updated [your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uhxpmexe/5/)

```js
function fHardCodedFunction(){
alert("bindee");
}

$('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
  var radioButId = $(this).attr('id');
  var value = $(this).val();
    console.log(value + " is clicked");
    
    if(value === "home")
    {
        console.log("Enable Loan Link")
        $("#ba").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
    if(value === "dog")
    {
        console.log("Disable Loan Link");
        $( "#ba").attr( "disabled","disabled" );
    }   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
When Dog clicked, Load should disable and when home clicked, Load should be enable <br>
<input type="radio" class="p27" id ="ba" name="ins_type1" value="loan" checked="checked" /> Loan<br><br>

Click here:
<input type="radio" class="p27" id ="ba2" name="ins_type2" value="home" /> Home 
<input type="radio" class="p27" id ="ba3" name="ins_type2" value="dog" />
Dog
```

Notice that when the `disabled` attribute is present, clicking the button does not do anything. Besides, it visually greys out the button.

I have also used `console.log`, because debugging with `alert` sucks :)

Comment: i must not use disabled as it is requirement

Comment: Well you didn't mention any requirement in your question.

Comment: Can we bind a JQuery without mentioning function? <- This was my question

Comment: Yep, and where in that is "Another requirement is, I can't use disabled" ? :)

Answer (score 0):

use on and off instead of bind and unbind

check the following link

https://api.jquery.com/off/

Comment: Please add the relevant code in your answer itself.